# How to Run "docker exec -it <container_name > bash" using Gradle Build?

Tags: shell, docker, gradle, docker-compose, exec

I want to run " docker exec -it bash -c './tmp/script.sh' " this command using gradle from build.gradle. But this command does not work though "docker ps -a" command works fine

I tried in different way, but no luck

```
1) "docker-compose exec resin_container bash -c './resin/bin/resin-shutdown.sh'".execute().waitFor()

2) CommandLine "docker-compose exec resin_container bash -c './resin/bin/resin-shutdown.sh'"

3) exec{
  executable = 'sh'
  args "docker-compose exec resin_container bash -c './resin/bin/resin-shutdown.sh'"
}
```

Full code on build.gradle are as bellow

```
task dockerDeploy(dependsOn: 'tarArtifact') {
   group = "dev"
   description = 'Create exploded-war, tar it and deploy to docker'

   doLast {
       if (devEnvironment) {
           if ("docker inspect -f '{{.State.Running}}' resin_container".execute().text.contains('true')) {
              println "SHUTTING DOWN Resin Service"
              "docker-compose ps".execute().waitFor()
              //"docker-compose exec resin_container bash -c './resin/bin/resin-shutdown.sh'".execute().waitFor()

             def resin_shutdown = "docker exec -it resin_container bash -c \"./resin/bin/resin-shutdown.sh\""
            println "${resin_shutdown}"

            exec{
                //commandLine = 'docker ps'
                commandLine = resin_shutdown

            }

            println "RESTARTING resin_container"
            "docker-compose restart resin_container".execute().waitFor()

        } else {
            println "STARTING services"
            "docker-compose up -d".execute()
        }
      }
    }
 }
```

Expected result like bellow . In here I run the command from shell terminal, but I want to run the same command using  gradle build

```
  uzzal$ docker exec -it resin_container bash -c "./resin/bin/resin- 
  shutdown.sh"
  + GREEN='\033[1;32m'
  + NC='\033[0m'
  + echo 'NODE_NAME : '
  NODE_NAME :
  + pushd .
  + echo 'Waiting for server to stop'
  Waiting for server to stop
  + sleep 3
  + pgrep -fl -U 999 resin.jar
  + awk '{ print $1 }'
  + xargs kill -SIGTERM
  + sleep 3
  + echo -e '\033[1;32m DONE SHUTTING DOWN \033[0m '
  DONE SHUTTING DOWN
  + popd
  uzzal$
```

But Output comes as

```
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:shutResin'.

  > A problem occurred starting process 'command 'docker exec -it resin_container bash -c "./resin/bin/resin-shutdown.sh"''
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: Installing software into a running container usually isn't considered a best practice.  You should write a Dockerfile that COPYs the artifact in question in, and during your build, `docker stop; docker rm` the existing container and then `docker build; docker run` a new one.

Comment: @DavidMaze, thanks for quick reply. Install software is not my concern here. I want to run a script into a running container during every new build. So that it will gracefully shutdown my server before restart container, So I'm looking  for best practice

Comment: Best practice IME is to build a new image on every build, and then launch a new container with the new image.  The very careful steps you’re describing here to keep a specific container alive with a set of hand-installed software and a hand-managed lifecycle isn’t usually how I’ve seen Docker used.